# Refactor foreach to for loop

Tags: java, eclipse, automated-refactoring

I have a foreach loop in Java (simplified version here)

```
List<String> names = getNames();
for(String name:names) {
    doSomething(name);
}
```

Is there an automated way to refactor this to a traditional `for` loop?

I know how to do it manually

```
List<String> names = getNames();
for(int i=0; i<names.size(); i++) {
    String name = names.get(i);
    doSomething(name);
}
```

As you can see, there is a bit of typing needed in the `for` statement itself as well as introducing the variable `name` again and assign it the value `names.get(i)`. In total, the manual edit is too error-prone for me.

Why do I want to do this? I have to fix a bug and the fix is to start at index 1 instead of index 0 and end at index n-1 instead of the end (unfortunately I can't fix the input right away, I need to wait for a library update if that's recognized as a bug).

What have I tried? I right-clicked on the `for` keyword and clicked on "Refactor", but as far as I can get from the context menu entries, nothing in there would do the work for me.

Why do I think this could theoretically work? Because similar functionality exists in Resharper for Visual Studio (C#).

FYI: I'm using Eclipse Luna SR 2 (4.4.2)

Comment: Is it possible to introduce a new method instead of 'getNames' which returns the list without first and last items ?

Comment: @DevBlanked: of course that would technically be possible, but doesn't that mean I manually write a loop that copies everything except the first and the last item?

Comment: not really, you could remove the first & last items giving their indexes, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(int).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mouseover the `for` statement, right-click, Quick fix (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>), convert to indexed loop.

Should work!

Comment: Then call it the `ctrl+1` action… btw, you don’t need to highlight the `for` statement, having the cursor besides it is enough.

Comment: @Thomas, to be precise Eclipse offers "quick fixes" for correcting problems (errors/warnings), and "quick assists" for other typical modifications. Loop conversion is a "quick assist". Only for convenience are both actions bound to `ctrl-1`.

Answer (score 7):

```
List<String> names = getNames();
names = names.subList(1, names.size() - 1);
for(String name : names) {
    doSomething(name);
}
```

Of course, you could put that into a reusable method if you need to do it several times:

```
public static List<String> fixList(List<String> names) {
    return names.subList(1, names.size() - 1);
}
```

and then use it as

```
List<String> names = fixList(getNames());
for(String name : names) {
    doSomething(name);
}
```

Comment: Ok, not exactly what I asked for, but definitely nice because if I get the library update, I just have to remove one line of code (doing the fix).

Comment: This solves the problem you would've had if you got the answer you where looking for :) I would change `fixList` to `trimList` and add arguments `beginIndex` and `endIndex` making the function more reusable.

Answer (score 6):

In my eclipse (Kepler RC2) it works to select the `for` keyword and either use the quick fix from the context menu or hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> for the shortcut. Eclipse then offers me "Convert to indexed 'for' loop" or "Convert to Iterator-based 'for' loop".

[image: Screenshot of quick fix options]

Answer (score 1):

You can use either:

```
names = names.subList(1, names.size()-1);
for (String name : names) {
   doSomething(name);
}
```

or in manually:

```
for (int i = 1; i < names.size()-1; i++) {
   String name = names.get(i);
    doSomething(name);
}
```

But the first one I prefer to use.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with this refactoring.

The reason is that for a traditional linked list, your second `for` loop formulation is O(N * N) since you're having to traverse the linked list in order to evaluate `names.get(i);`. That could become expensive.

Do consider performance implications when moving from `for(String name:names) {`. There may well be a better way of fixing your immediate bug, and retaining the current "Big O".

`for(String name : names.subList(1, names.size() - 1)) {`

is one such way (Acknowledge @JB Nizet).

Comment: While correct in principle, no sane programmer uses `LinkedList` anyway. It’s advantage of `O(1)` insertion cost pays off only at such big lists that its disadvantage of insanely higher per-element memory consumption makes it unusable.

Answer (score 0):

Don't go for indexed iteration!
This does not perform well with all implementations of `List`.

It is much better to go for an `Iterator` and let the JIT optimize the `Iterator` away if this code is hot.

So either write this:

```
List<String> names = getNames();
for (String name : names.subList(1, names.size() - 1)) {
    doSomething(name);
}
```

Or that (one allocation less):

```
Iterator<String> it = getNames().iterator();
it.next(); // You seem to be sure there is more than one element in the list
while (it.hasNext()) {
    String name = it.next();
    doSomething(name);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I need to transform the foreach to use an index .
This is my two cents

```
Integer index=0;
                  
      for (final String OneCell :CellList){
     // Your code use the index
             index=index+1;
     }
```

Answer (score -2):

When using java 8 you could use the stream api

```
names.stream().skip(1).reverse().skip(1).reverse().foreach(
    name -> do something(name)
);
```

Something like this...

Comment: There is no reverse() method on Stream.

Comment: Besides that this is not what the questioner asked for; there is no `reverse` method on `Stream` and `forEach` does not respect the source order, therefore `forEachOrdered` is needed.